DrawingContext's PushEffect function is Deprecated, is there a workaround for dynamically adding effects?
I have a custom control I made to handle the rendering of composite images with effects. I want to apply custom shader effects to specific elements of this control's render, but the built in PushEffect & PopEffect functions, which would do this easily, are deprecated and do nothing.
So, to meet my ends I've created a new DrawingVisual and have drawn my images to that visual, and applied the effect to said visual which all seemed great. However, to get my controls to draw the image I need to run it through RenderTargetBitmap which blows away my custom effect as it doesnt render effects compiled in Shader Model 3 or higher.
My question boils down to this:

Is there a way to have the built in OnRender DrawingContext draw another contexts image without passing it though RenderTargetBitmap? Maybe a way to compile multiple drawing contexts without converting them into images first? I am aware of drawing groups, but I'm not sure how to use them with OnRender.

Please note that my goal is to do this in code behind, so XAML solutions will not be too useful. I am also open to hearing alternative ways to apply effects to specific elements of a custom control that I may be missing.
All on .Net Framework 4.7.2, if it matters.
public class CustomControl : FrameworkElement
{
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

        // Retrieve the DrawingContext in order to create new drawing content.
        DrawingContext drawingVisualContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();

        // Create a rectangle and draw it in the DrawingVisual.
        Rect rect = new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Size(200, 400));
        drawingVisualContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.LightBlue, null, rect);

        // Persist the visual's content.
        drawingVisualContext.Close();

        // Note: using the built in Blur or DropShadow effects will work fine. Specifically, to 
        // reproduce, youll need a custom effect that is complied in Shadermodel 3 or later.
        // To obtain a custom effect you will need to build one yourself or look into Shazzam
        // (https://github.com/JohanLarsson/Shazzam) - an old tool I specifically use to create 
        // custom effects
        drawingVisual.Effect = new CustomEffect();
        //drawingVisual.Effect = new BlurEffect() { Radius = 25 };

        // This will remove our custom effect since it uses software rendering afaik, which Shader 
        // Model 3 cannot be rendered with
        RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)200, (int)400, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
        bitmap.Render(drawingVisual);

        drawingContext.DrawImage(bitmap, rect);
    }
}


Have you considered the "Visual Host" approach, as explained here?

As Clemens recommended in the comments, I solved this by creating a visual host and adding it to my control. From there, I created visual children in my constructor, and  applied different effects to each child as needed without issue.
